# Execute transformation steps on the blocking thread for Mono

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactive-streams

Is there a way to ensure that all transformation steps for a single `Mono` that created from a future are executed on the thread that subscribes and blocks?

For instance, the following code

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  var future = new CompletableFuture<String>();
  var res = Mono.fromFuture(future).map(val -> {
    System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return val + "1";
  });

  new Thread(() -> {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    future.complete("completed");
  }, "completer").start();

  res.block();
}
```

prints `Thread: completer` because the future is completed from the "completer" thread. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to make it always print `Thread: main`.

Answer (score 3):

No.  When the `main` thread is blocked via `.block()`, that thread is specifically waiting for the `onNext`, `onComplete`, or `onError` signals of the stream (after all the upstream operators have executed).  It does *not* somehow regain control *before* the upstream operators are invoked in order to execute the operators.

The closest thing you can do would be to ensure that:

1. the subscription is executed on a specific `Scheduler` (via `.subscribeOn`) AND
2. the future's completion value is published on the same `Scheduler` (via `.publishOn`).

For example:

```java
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.parallel();
var res = Mono.fromFuture(future)
        .doFirst(() -> {   // Note: doFirst added in 3.2.10.RELEASE
            // prints a thread in the parallel Scheduler (specified by subscribeOn below)
            System.out.println("Subscribe Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        })
        // specifies the Scheduler on which the the completion value
        // from above is published for downstream operators
        .publishOn(scheduler)
        .map(val -> {
            // prints a thread in the parallel Scheduler (specified by publishOn above)
            System.out.println("Operator Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()); 
            return val + "1";
        })
        // specifies the Scheduler on which  upstream operators are subscribed
        .subscribeOn(scheduler);
```

However, note the following:

- The subscribe occurs on a thread in the `Scheduler`, *not* the blocked `main` thread.
- This approach just ensures that the same `Scheduler` is used, not the same `Thread` within the `Scheduler`.  You could theoretically force the same `Thread` by using a single-threaded scheduler  (e.g. `Schedulers.newParallel("single-threaded", 1)`)
- The `.publishOn` does not *enforce* that *all* operators operate on that `Scheduler`.  It just affects downstream operators until the next `.publishOn`, or until the next async operator (such as `.flatMap`) which might utilize a different `Scheduler`.

Answer (score 0):

As a very non-optimised proof of concept, this can be achieved in the following way:

Let's create an executor which is able to execute tasks "on demand" in a controlled way.

```java
private static class SelfEventLoopExecutor implements Executor {
  private final LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

  @Override
  public void execute(Runnable command) {
    boolean added = queue.add(command);
    assert added;
  }

  public void drainQueue() {
    Runnable r;
    while ((r = queue.poll()) != null) {
      r.run();
    }
  }
}
```

Next, create a subscriber which is able to use the executor to execute the tasks while waiting for the result instead of completely blocking the thread.

```java
public static class LazyBlockingSubscriber<T> implements Subscriber<T> {
  private final SelfEventLoopExecutor selfExec;
  private volatile boolean completed = false;
  private volatile T value;
  private volatile Throwable ex;

  public LazyBlockingSubscriber(SelfEventLoopExecutor selfExec) {
    this.selfExec = selfExec;
  }

  @Override
  public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
    s.request(1);
  }

  @Override
  public void onNext(T t) {
    value = t;
    completed = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(Throwable t) {
    ex = t;
    completed = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onComplete() {
    completed = true;
  }

  public T block() throws Throwable {
    while (!completed) {
      selfExec.drainQueue();
    }
    if (ex != null) {
      throw ex;
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

Now, we can modify the code in the following way

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
  var future = new CompletableFuture<String>();

  var selfExec = new SelfEventLoopExecutor(); // our new executor

  var res = Mono.fromFuture(future)
      .publishOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(selfExec))  // schedule on the new executor
      .map(val -> {
        System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return val + "1";
      });

  new Thread(() -> {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    future.complete("completed");
  }, "completer").start();

  var subs = new LazyBlockingSubscriber<String>(selfExec); // lazy subscribe
  res.subscribeWith(subs);
  subs.block(); // spin wait
}
```

As a result, the code prints `Thread: main`.